# Component CommentListComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

when i need to go in `CommentListComment` it show me this Error :

> Component CommentListComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

this is my code :

```
  @NgModule({
  declarations: [CommentListComponent, CourseCommentComponent, CommentAddComponent, CommentEditComponent, CommentFiltersComponent, CommentReplyComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,

    // routing module imported here
    LessonCommentRoutingModule,

    CommonModule,
    CoreModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    PartialsModule,
    TranslateModule.forChild(),
    Angular2PromiseButtonModule.forRoot(promiseButtonConfig),
    SharedModule
  ],
  exports:[CommentListComponent, CourseCommentComponent, CommentAddComponent, CommentEditComponent, CommentFiltersComponent, CommentReplyComponent]
})
```

and this is my LessonCommentRoutingModule:

```
{
    path: '', component: CommentListComponent
    , data: {
        permission: {
            permittedRoles: [':CourseLessonComment:GetAllManager'],
            deniedRoles: null
        } as AuthGuardPermission,
        breadcrumb: 'Course Comments'
    }
},
{
    path: 'list',
    component: CommentListComponent,
    data: {
        permission: {
            permittedRoles: [':CourseLessonComment:GetAllManager'],
            deniedRoles: null
        } as AuthGuardPermission,
        breadcrumb: 'List',
    },
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
{
    path: 'list/:lessonId',
    component: CommentListComponent,
    data: {
        permission: {
            permittedRoles: [':CourseLessonComment:GetAllManager'],
            deniedRoles: null
        } as AuthGuardPermission,
        breadcrumb: 'List',
    },
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
```

**Whats the Problem ? How can I Solve This ???**

**Edit :**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'kt-comment-list',
    templateUrl: './comment-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./comment-list.component.scss']
})
export class CommentListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
    dataSource: CommentDataSource;
.............
```

Comment: check your import paths in your module and your routing file as your code seems fine

Comment: they are same . .

Comment: can you post your `CommentListComponent` code here from top till constructor.Also try restarting your server

Comment: Why did you import `CommonModule` twice?

Comment: @TheUnreal i remove one of them now . . .

Comment: @jitender i edit the questino

Comment: if you  are using lazy loading check your file app.routing.ts file

Comment: @kianoushdortaj your code seems fine check for typos as specified about `CommonModule` above or try creating a stackblitz

Comment: 1. can you post the whole component list component ?
2. can you post the module that imports the routing module that uses the component list component ?

Comment: @SaMiCoOo this is all of them

Comment: so lessonCommentRoutingModule is the routing module above ?

Comment: @SaMiCoOo yes man